# Why is the output not [1,12,6,[15]] but [1,3,6,[15]]?

Tags: python, list

```
x = [1,3,6,[18]]
y = list(x)
x[3][0] = 15
x[1] = 12
print(y)
```

The output is [1,3,6,[15]], why are not all the changes reflected on y.

Comment: By doing `list(x)` you are making a *copy* of the list.  Try just doing `y=x`.

Comment: I assume you are asking why your changes in x did not change the value of y. You set y to the value of x and that is it. Nothing you do to x will affect y unless you set y to the pointer of x. I would explain your problem more clearly in the future

Comment: You created a shallow copy of x and stored it in y.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70410679/17635987

Comment: even if y is a copy, x[3][0] gets reflected on y but not x[1], that is actually my question.

Comment: Because you created a *shallow* copy, not a deep one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does list() function is not letting me change the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70410679/why-does-list-function-is-not-letting-me-change-the-list)

Answer (score 0):

`y = list(x)` creates a (new) list from the iterable elements in x - even if x is already a list. This is different from `y = x` where y now just references the same list object as x.

This also explains why the last element is changed in your example. The last element in the x-list is actually a reference to another list. When this reference is copied as part of the `y = list(x)` operation it behaves like the `y = x` case, so now you have two references to this one list, one in `x[3]` and the other one in `y[3]`.

So when you access this list reference through `x[3]` and change the content, `y[3]` will show the changed content.

To make the difference clear, replace `x[3][0] = 15` with `x[3] = [15]`. Now you have changed the list reference in `x[3]` to a reference to a new list while `y[3]` still references the original sublist and is thus independent now.

You may want to read the relevant [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)